# get some links from an HTML string

Tags: c#

I have some strings with the content like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/2014/06/22/new-idea-about-life.zip">One</a>
<a href="http://example.com/2014/06/22/new-idea-about-life-rar.rar">Two</a>
```

I need this output:

```
http://example.com/2014/06/22/new-idea-about-life.zip
http://example.com/2014/06/22/new-idea-about-life-rar.rar
```

Comment: Take a look at html agility pack. It is a library that makes working with html strings or files easier. Supports linq-to-objects amongst other things. Also allows you to extract attributes from tags, which is what you need to do here.

Comment: thanks. does it have help? i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) is a good library to parse HTML in C#.

An example for extracting urls is:

```
var html = "<a href=\"http://reallife.com/2014/06/22/new-idea-about-life.zip\">New idea about life (zip) (25MB)</a><a href=\"http://reallife.com/2014/06/22/new-idea-about-life-rar.rar\">New idea about life (rar) (23MB)</a>
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var links = new List<string>();
foreach (var link in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    links.Add(link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));    
}
// do something with the links inside the links-List
```

Comment: i wrote this but i got these erors http://uupload.ir/files/ksa2_untitled.png

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You need to install the library via nuget. Have you done this? If yes, then you need to reference it.